# unable to combine sort order with searching in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Searching works well but sorting is not working. Please help?

```
@accounts1 = Account.search(params[:search])
@accounts = @accounts1.paginate(:order =>(sort_column + " " + sort_direction),
                                :per_page => 5,
                                :page => params[:accounts_page])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 3+ you should try something like this:

```
@accounts = Account.search(params[:search]).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").paginate(:page => params[:accounts_page], :per_page => 5)
```

Where does the `search` method come from?